# How to call an async function after a state change, in order to change another state dynamically?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make an API call (to infura) that uses the users ethereum address (which is fetched from metamask, a browser add-on that keeps your ethereum addresses). Metamask allows the user to switch between addresses whenever they want. My react App does respond to an address change correctly (shows the right address).

The problem however is that while the address (and the corresponding state) does update, I can not call the async function that calls the API as soon as the state changes. Forcing me to have to refresh the whole window in order to get the updated API response. The function I am trying to call works fine by itself, I just can't call it after a state change.

I have tried several ways of calling the function, but all of them show similar errors, Usually ReferenceError.

I have tried this binding (but maybe I didn't do it properly).

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      ethereum: window.ethereum,
      address: "",
      whitelisted: "scanning whitelist..."
    };
  }

  render() {
     return null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      this.setState({ address: window.ethereum.selectedAddress });
      window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", accounts => {
        this.setState({ address: accounts[0] });
        foo(); // --> this works
      });
    }

 function foo() {
      console.log("update"); // -> this works
      update(); // -> this breaks
    }

    async function checkWhitelist() {
      try {
        let res = await axios.get(
          "https://api.infura.io/v1/jsonrpc/mainnet/eth_call?params=[{%22to%22:%220xdd5cec9019ec8449a5d01d0d8175e6519530d276%22,%22data%22:%220x08e0d29d000000000000000000000000" +
            window.ethereum.selectedAddress.substring(2) +
            "%22},%22latest%22]"
        );
        let r = res.data.result;
        this.setState({ whitelisted: r[r.length - 1] });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }

    let update = checkWhitelist.bind(this)();
  }
}
```

Expected behavior: 
Run the function "checkWhitelist" whenever the "address" state updates to check the whitelist status of the address that is currently loaded in the state.

Actual result:
As soon as I call an async function it breaks and gives:
Uncaught TypeError: update is not a function

Synchronous functions work just fine, until the sync function calls an async function.

---

### EDIT

I managed to get it to work by making an anonymous async function at the place where I want the code to execute. It is functional, but this is repeated code and it's a bit ugly, I'd like to know what is the 'proper' way of doing it.

Here's the updated piece of relevant code, it's a bit 'hacky'

```
if (window.ethereum) {
  this.setState({ address: window.ethereum.selectedAddress });
  window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", accounts => {
    this.setState({ address: accounts[0] });
    (async () => {
      let res = await axios.get(
        "https://api.infura.io/v1/jsonrpc/mainnet/eth_call?params=[{%22to%22:%220xdd5cec9019ec8449a5d01d0d8175e6519530d276%22,%22data%22:%220x08e0d29d000000000000000000000000" +
          window.ethereum.selectedAddress.substring(2) +
          "%22},%22latest%22]"
      );
      let r = res.data.result;
      this.setState({ whitelisted: r[r.length - 1] });
    })();
  });
}
```

---

### EDIT 2

After the suggestions from @octobus I managed to get it to work like this:

```
   if (window.ethereum) {
  this.setState({ address: window.ethereum.selectedAddress });
  window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", accounts => {
    this.setState({ address: accounts[0] });
    checkWhiteList();
  });
}

let checkWhiteList = async () => {
  let res = await axios.get(
    "https://api.infura.io/v1/jsonrpc/mainnet/eth_call?params=[{%22to%22:%220xdd5cec9019ec8449a5d01d0d8175e6519530d276%22,%22data%22:%220x08e0d29d000000000000000000000000" +
      window.ethereum.selectedAddress.substring(2) +
      "%22},%22latest%22]"
  );
  let r = res.data.result;
  console.log(r[r.length - 1]);
  this.setState({ whitelisted: r[r.length - 1] });
};
```

}
}

Comment: I have left out the render function because I don't think it's helpful to the question, but if necessary of course I can share it.

Comment: `update` is a local variable, so inside your `foo` function, it is undefined. That's the reason of the error.

Comment: @octobus thank you, I had a feeling it had to do with scope, could you tell me how to ensure I can call "update" from foo? The answer is probably going to be embarrassing, but I'm self-taught in programming and i'm pretty new to react.

Comment: You should make your checkWhiteList function, an arrow function and then you should call it with `this.checkWhiteList (); instead of calling with `update`

Comment: @octobus, after some fiddling with your suggestion I got that to work. Thanks.